# Is it possible to install Citus extension on official Postgres binary?

Tags: postgresql, citus

I don't want to use the Citus provided binary for PostgreSQL server. Since Citus it is an extension, I believe it should play well with the official Postgres server binary.

Answer (score 1):

@Dojo, you can follow the instructions from the latest documents to install binaries for citus for many operating systems.

http://docs.citusdata.com/en/v9.2/installation/single_machine.html

Citus does only support PostgreSQL 11 & 12 major versions and trigger installation of PostgreSQL for those versions when you follow the instructions for binary installation (naturally).

You could still prefer to build & install citus binaries by following the instructions in GitHub page. However, it is not recommended to use citus with unsupported PostgreSQL versions.

Comment: Those instructions install Postgres from Citus' PPA. What I am looking for is just the plugin installation manual where Postgres binary is from official Postgres PPA or website.

Comment: The Github page, which I had already checked, also has no mention of a plugin only install. They do not provide a binary plugin. IMHO if something is called a plugin they should provide the binary just as a plugin and not require everyone to use their prepackaged PostgreSQL variant.

Comment: Citus is not a plugin, but an extension. Having a single `executable` is not enough to install citus. The number of files that need to be copied are high, and the destination changes accoding to the postgresql configuration options.

You can always extract the contents of a package, and examine the contents. However I do not recommend you try to manually install everything including but not limited to: the shared object, control file, sql migration scripts, c headers, .bc files for LLVM JIT support etc

Answer (score 0):

Citus team provides binaries for Citus extension itself but doesn't provide PostgreSQL binaries (maybe in some repositories for convenience). So you can use the official postgres binary with Citus. You don't even need to use Citus provided binaries and you can compile it yourself.

Comment: I tried looking for the binary on Citus' website and on Github. I could not locate the binary. Do you know where to get it from?